# Drive API multi login iframe issue

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using drive api in my app and it works well , but sometimes when multiple users are logged in and I try to open a file in the browser with the link fetched via drive api I see the error message "You need permission. Want in? Ask the owner for access, or switch to an account with permission. Learn more" .

Steps to reproduce :

1. login to google drive with one account.
2. login with a second account and use drive api.
3. when you try to open public files you get that error.

If you add access token in url it seems to resolve the issue but thats a security risk. If you add authuser param to url that also works, but I can't find a way to get current user's authuser param.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The "authuser" param can be extracted using 'request.getParameter("authuser")' in oauth2callback servlet

Comment: @AbhijeetKumarGaur, Thanks for your suggestion. I tested , but request.getParameter("authuser") is null. Its not part of the callback url from google.

Comment: Could you paste in the screenshot which you recieve while accessing file. And check in your browser developer tools for "oauth2callback"  servlet call. It contains [authuser param](https://imgur.com/ySeiE63) as query string.

Comment: @AbhijeetKumarGaur , I debugged and printed request params on oauth callback, there is no auth user param. Only standard oauth params are sent by google.

the error you see is the standard google drive permission screen which says "You need permission

Want in? Ask the owner for access, or switch to an account with permission. Learn more

You are signed in as  xxxx@gmail.com"